# Codeigniter - Limit items in query "where_in"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I would like limiting the results for every id (only 3 results for array id).

If I add:

```
$this->db->limit(3);
```

I receive three records in total; but I want 3 record for every id.

How can I do?

```
<?php

$array = array('id' => 1, 'id' => 2, 'id' => 3);

class Your_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);     
    }

    public function function_name()
    {
        $this->db->select('file_name');
        $this->db->from('images_table');
        $this->db->where_in('id', $array);            
        $query = $this->db->get();                  

        $result = "";
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            $result = $query->result_array();
        else
            $result = "No result";

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to get n records per group i.e each id in your array is a group which can have many file_names associated to it.

### First approach

Using mysql's `GROUP_CONCAT` with a combination of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.What it does `GROUP_CONCAT` will concatenate all the values in your column i.e `file_name` with a separator which you can define as you wish to, in below query i have used double pipe `||`,second `SUBSTRING_INDEX`  with limit of 3 will get the 3 places of provided separator from the string provided by `GROUP_CONCAT`

> But beaware of that fact GROUP_CONCAT has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat so if there many file_names per id they will be truncated,but default limit of GROUP_CONCAT can be increased by setting a session variable which is defined in GROUP_CONCAT's manual

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT( file_name SEPARATOR '||'),
'||',3) images
FROM images_table p
GROUP BY p.id
```

You can view the sample results in below provided demo

Now at your application level you just have to loop through the products and split the images by separator

**Active record query**

```
$results=$this->db->select('SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT( file_name SEPARATOR '||'),
'||',3) images',FALSE)
     ->from('images_table p')
     ->group_by('p.id')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();

foreach($results as $row):
$images =explode('||',$row['images ']);
    foreach($images as $m):
    ....
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34a56/10)

### Second Approach

Other method you can use user defined variables in your query to give rank to the items of each group

```
SELECT file_name,rank FROM(
SELECT file_name,
@r:= CASE WHEN id = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END rank 
,@g:=id
FROM images_table,(SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t
ORDER BY id
  ) t
 WHERE rank < 4
```

Now this query can't be written using active record so you have to use simple `query()` function

```
    $results=$this->db
           ->query('SELECT file_name,rank FROM(
                    SELECT file_name,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN id = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END rank 
                    ,@g:=id
                    FROM images_table,(SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t
                    ORDER BY id
                    ) t
                    WHERE rank < 4');
```

You can view the sample results in below provided demo

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34a56/15)

**Edit from comments**

To pass your array of ids just use active record's `where_in()`

```
$results=$this->db->select('SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT( file_name SEPARATOR '||'),
'||',3) images',FALSE)
     ->from('images_table p')
     ->where_in('p.id', $array)
     ->group_by('p.id')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();
```

And for raw query you can do so

```
    $results=$this->db
           ->query('SELECT file_name,rank FROM(
                    SELECT file_name,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN id = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END rank 
                    ,@g:=id
                    FROM images_table,(SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t
                    WHERE id IN('.join(",",$array).')
                    ORDER BY id
                    ) t
                    WHERE rank < 4');
```

Comment: In my specific case, I have an array that contains "id"; how can I pass the array to the query in codeigniter?